# Modifying a primereact module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, primereact

I'm trying to use "autocomplete" module of primereact, however it's missing a little thing that I want to add. But if I make my modifications in node_modules, it just reverts back to original whenever I update the package. Is there any way to make modifications and make them stay? Or can I just copy the package from my node_modules to my project, so it acts like my own component? I'd rather not prefer this since I wouldn't be able to get updates but still it would be the last resort.
Thanks

Comment: 1) Is there anyway...? **No** 2) Or can I just copy...? **Yes**. You can request for that feature you need in the [primereact github issues](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues) page. You might get a quick `alternative solution` to your problem (or) if they consider your **feature request**, they will add it in future releases.

Comment: 1) You can make your own autocomplete component with your extra feature using the primereact's autocomplete component. 2) You can and should open an issue and suggest a pull request with your feature implemented so that they can add your feature in next versions.